# How to collapse data by week correctly in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have a transaction level dataset and I want to collapse and calculate weekly average price. The dataset can be simplified as follows,

```
clear 
input str9 date quantity price id
"01jan2010" 50 70 1
"02jan2010" 60 80 2
"02jan2010" 70 90 3
"04jan2010" 70 95 4
"08jan2010" 60 81 5
"09jan2010" 70 88 6
"12jan2010" 55 87 7
"13jan2010" 52 88 8
end
gen date2=date(date,"DMY")
format date2 %td
drop date
```

I want to create a variable `date3`. For every transaction happened in a week, `date3` is the Monday of that week.

Here's the code I have:

```
sort date2
gen date3=date2 if dow(date2)==1
replace date3=date3[_n-1] if missing(date3)
format date3 %td
```

However, there are Mondays with no transactions, but the rest of the week has transactions. In those cases, `date3` is not the Monday date of that week, but Monday date in the weeks before.

My data becomes the following using the above code:

```
quantity    price   id  date2       date3
50          70  1   01jan2010   
60          80  2   02jan2010   
70          90  3   02jan2010   
70          95  4   04jan2010   04jan2010
60          81  5   08jan2010   04jan2010
70          88  6   09jan2010   04jan2010
55          87  7   12jan2010   04jan2010
52          88  8   13jan2010   04jan2010
```

To me, it does not matter if `id` =1,2,3 have no `date3`. What I am concerned is that `id`=7 and `id`=8 should have a `date3` of 11jan2010. But because there is no transaction on that day, the date becomes 04jan2010. Is there a way to fix this?

(I was thinking of constructing a new dataset with consecutive dates since 01jan2010 and then `merge` with the one above, and then `drop` if missing quantity of price. But I was wondering if there's a more efficient way).

---

In addition, I have a weekly index data that reports on every Friday since 01jan2010. If I use `wofd` command, Stata will generate 53 weeks in 2010. (Or more precisely, two 2010w52.) How can I get just 52 weeks in Stata?

(I found this http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-02/msg01030.html but I still cannot figure out how this can help solve my problem. )

Comment: When working with weeks, [Stata tip 68: Week assumptions](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0052) by Nick Cox, is a good read.

Comment: `merge` is not as bad as you think. I would encourage you to try that path and report any problems.

Comment: In fact, you should report the complete attempt (i.e. include the code).

Comment: Thank you @robertoferrer, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your weeks start on Mondays. Everything you need follows from using `dow()` to exploit the fact that in every one of your weeks, the day of week function `dow()` yields 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0 for the days from Monday to Sunday.

The present or previous Monday for daily dates `daily` is just

```
 gen Monday = cond(dow(daily) == 0, daily - 6, daily - dow(daily) + 1)
```

The branch is like this. If it's a Sunday, the previous Monday was 6 days ago. Otherwise, the Monday that starts the week was today if it's Monday and `dow()` yields 1,  yesterday if it's Tuesday and 2, and so forth.  Here the variable `Monday` is just the dates of Mondays that define the weeks.

Important detail: There are no assumptions here about dates being complete in the data or even in order.

Small note: Arbitrary names like `date2` and `date3` mean nothing much. Use evocative names in your questions (and your practice).

There was a sequel to the article mentioned by Robert Ferrer. `search week, sj` in Stata to get the references.

Do **not** use Stata's weeks and in particular do **not** use the `wofd()` function (not a command), as they can't help you. Stata's weeks will not map on to your weeks. The article mentioned by Robert Ferrer really is worthwhile reading to understand this (even though I wrote it).

(This is all explained in the Statalist threads you link to.)

Comment: Thank you Nick! This is really helpful!